# Как создавать приложения для работы на двух мониторах?

Tags: c#, wpf

Каков принцип создания таких приложений? Это что-то типа презентации. На одном мониторе управляющее окно, на другом вывод изображения/текста

Comment: Перечитайте свой вопрос, вы уже ответили на него сами. Два и более независимых окна для одного приложения и есть решение.

Comment: Это первое, что пришло мне в голову, но может есть какие-то другие способы?

Comment: Можно и по-другому: пишем свой оконный менеджер, прикручиваем гвоздями к ОС, прибиваем шурупами совместимость со всем остальным софтом, и наслаждаемся. Только это уже не .NET, и тем более не WPF. Да и уровень просветления совсем другой потребуется

Comment: Если вас такой вариант не устраивает - подскажите примеры, как хочется видеть приложение? Потому что я пока не видел ни одного, которое бы вело себя корректно сразу на двух мониторах. На одном из двух - вполне, но не на обоих сразу, объема данных обычно такого нет.

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть 2 варианта:

1. Классический.
   Приложение имеет несколько окон, которые либо независимы по определению, как в Gimp или Lazarus, или могут быть вложенными либо независимыми по желанию пользователя, как в Visual Studio.
2. Альтернативным вариантом, если не брать в расчет экзотику, можно попробовать реализовать возможность запуска основного окна в полно-экранном режиме на одном мониторе, а управление вынести стандартными окнами на другой. Такой вариант используется, например, в VLC.

В любом случае у вас будет много-оконный интерфейс с независимым размещением окон.

PS: В какой-то из старых редакций Windows, чуть ли не XP, хотя могу ошибаться, под руками для тестов не имею, встречался вариант, когда, при использовании 2х мониторов в режиме расширения рабочего стола, максимизация окна приложения приводила к растягиванию окна на оба монитора сразу, и это было ужасно неудобно.

Comment: Растягивать на два окна не нужно. Нужно действительно два разных окна. А всякие DirectX или Direct3D ?

Comment: @МаксимКутовой ну WPF использует DirectX. Так что, вам тоже ни кто не мешает использовать. Можете и OpenGL прикрутить, если c DX-ом не в ладах